# Required Field conditional on button pressed

Tags: asp.net, validation

I may be having a blonde moment here.

I have a data entry form with the usual "Save" and "Cancel" buttons.  In addition to these two I have another button "Approve".  If the user clicks the "Approve" button I have an additional field (Approver) that must hold data.  Is it possible to have a required field validator that is active on one button press but not another?

Comment: Use `ValidationGroup`

Comment: from the description i gather that the 2 ValidationGroups are overlapping on some of the fields

Comment: Yes all fields would belong to both groups except one field.

Comment: You can use multiple validation group and validate them using custom javascript function Onclientclick see my answer bellow for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes This is possible :
You can Define multiple Validation group and decide witch group to validate depending on the clicked button, for that you should call javascript function onClientClient in order to validate the inputs :

See example bellow:

[Triggering multiple validation groups with a single button](http://webagile.blogspot.com/2013/05/triggering-multiple-validation-groups.html)

Comment: Exactly what I needed thanks!  One question! :)  All the validators have a text value of * and the * appears beside each control that fails validation.  However the for Approver the error message is didplayed in the validation summary but the * doesnt appear.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to create a custom validator or just use javascript or jquery.

You can use the OnClientClick property of the buttons and add some javascript on there.

```
function CheckSave() {
  if (/*text1 is filled*/) return true;
}

function CheckApprove() {
  if (/*text1 is filled and text2 is filled*/) return true;
}

<asp:button id='btnSave' OnClientClick='return CheckSave()' OnClick='btnSave_Click' />    
<asp:button id='btnApprove' OnClientClick='return CheckApprove()' OnClick='btnAprove_Click' />
```

you need the **return** in order for it to work